# How to run android application on netneans 6.5?

Tags: android, netbeans, netbeans6.5

How to run android application on netbeans 6.5?

If i running the application means i got following error,

W/ResourceType( 1968): Bad string block: string #14 extends to 1847, past end at 60

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys it's only theory. I mean [nbandroid - Netbeans plugin for Android](http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/). It's still in deep beta (version 0.10) and is too buggy to be used for real development. I have spent several days trying to use it. In the end I have managed to run some simple HelloWorld alikes but for more complicated things - it's unworkable.

IMHO there are only 3 ways to develop Android applications: Eclipse, Intellij IDEA and from command line tools. My choice is Intellij IDEA - it's better than Eclipse equipped with Google's plugin.